# Performance of Sub query vs join

Tags: sql-server, join

I am executing following two queries and capturing estimated sub tree cost as well as statistic time

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

Select Id, Name, Description
from tblProducts
where ID IN
(
Select ProductId from tblProductSales
)

DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

Select distinct tblProducts.Id, Name, Description
from tblProducts
inner join tblProductSales
on tblProducts.Id = tblProductSales.ProductId
```

So, result I am getting is

> Estimated subtree cost(Subquery) - 0.458276
>   Estimated subtree cost(Join) - 0.458982

Statistic Time(Subquery):

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
>      CPU time = 16 ms, elapsed time = 163 ms.
>
> (7063 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:

> CPU time = 109 ms,  elapsed time = 726 ms.

Statistic Time(Join):

> SQL Server parse and compile time: 
>   CPU time = 16 ms, elapsed time = 654 ms.
>
> (7063 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> SQL Server Execution Times:
>      CPU time = 62 ms,  elapsed time = 624 ms.

So, We can see `join` CPU time(62 ms) is less than `subquery` CPU time(109 ms) but Estimated subtree cost is higher in `join` than `subquery`.

So, what is the conclusion who is performing better??

Comment: You're comparing estimates and actuals. Estimates are an estimation of the effort, used to evaluate the best plan, based on statistics, whereas CPU time is _actually_ what happened. If you are interested in the best performing query, you should try using `WHERE EXISTS` as well. Nowadays there may not be too much of a difference between the three

Comment: The execution timings aren't really helpful as they can be affected by many factors.  Use `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to see what reads were performed. The timings aren't really helpful. Also, are there any indexes on the tables? Are `tblProducts.Id` and `tblProductSales.ProductId` indexed?

Comment: A more performant query might be `Select distinct Id, Name, Description from tblProducts where exists (select * from tblProductSales where tblProducts.Id = tblProductSales.ProductId)`. This uses `exists`. In some cases this might be faster

Answer (score 0):

Estimated time can be misleading. Only live servers statistics is live and updated so localserver or something like that servers do not reflect the real estimated time.

Other point is, this two query is not ok. The true version of these two query is

`Select tblProducts.Id, Name, Description
from tblProducts
inner join tblProductSales
on tblProducts.Id = tblProductSales.ProductId
group by tblProducts.Id, Name, Description`

or something like that dont care th syntax. So before looking at the statistics you must consider that "Is this the best version of this query ?" if your answer is yes then consider statistics then your statistic result will be more meaningful.